# Small perimeter-minimizing disks on curved surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

Suppose that I have a smooth curved surface, and I choose an arbitrary point $Q$ on that surface. Say the Gaussian curvature at that point is $K$. What I am wondering is, is there an expression for the minimal perimeter $P_{min}$ of a disk of area $A$ which contains point $Q$, in the limit of a very small disk with $AK \ll 1$? What I imagine is something like

$$
P_{min} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}+\text{powers of $K$ or derivatives of $K$ at $Q$}
$$

The zeroth-order term comes from the planar case. My question is:

- Is such an expansion possible at all, and if it is, are any lowest order terms known?

I have searched but I could not find any result of the sort. For geodesic disks, I have used the [Bertrand–Diguet–Puiseux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%E2%80%93Diguet%E2%80%93Puiseux_theorem) to obtain

$$
P_{geo} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}} \left( 1 - \frac{AK}{8\pi} \right) + O(\sqrt{A}A^2K^2)
$$
or equivalently
$$
P_{geo}^2 = 4 \pi A - A^2 K + O(A^3K^2)
$$
which implies that a small geodesic disk of a given area will have larger perimeter in a negatively curved region than in a positively curved region. A second, weaker question is therefore

- Does a similar result hold for the small perimeter-minimizing disk? I.e. will $P_{min}$ always be larger for $K<0$ than for $K>0$ in the limit of small area?

Comment: Your terminology is not clear.  For example, what do you mean by a "geodesic disk"?  Is that a disk of constant Gaussian curvature?

Comment: No, it's the region enclosed by a geodesic circle. The geodesic circle of radius r centered at a point p is the set of all points whose geodesic distance from p is equal to r. But for an arbitrary surface, the geodesic disk thus defined is not necessarily the perimeter-minimizing disk, in the sense of the isoperimetric inequality. I am trying to find out if there is something that can be said about the mininal perimeter of infinitesimally small disks at a a surface, based on the local curvature of the surface.

Comment: That would be "distance sphere" (or "circle"), not "geodesic circle" but perhaps the authors you cited use this term.   Are you looking for a precise expression, or something like the formula that you reproduced from Bertrand et al.?

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion. I used the terminology that came in the Wikipedia page for Bertrand–Diguet–Puiseux theorem I linked above, and in the Wikipedia page for "geodesic circle" (although the latter says that this term is also sometimes used to refer to circles of constant geodesic curvature). The formula I gave above is not reproduced from Bertrand et al., rather derived from their two results for the limiting values of the area and the perimeter of the "distance circle", listed in the Wikipedia page of the theorem linked above.

Comment: I am looking for an expression for Pmin at least like the one that I give above for Pgeo, with the first nontrivial order (presumably going as AK), and ideally a notion of what kind of terms would come at higher orders in the expansion (higher powers of AK, derivatives of K...). Actually I suspect that the first order in Pmin will coincide with the first order of Pgeo I give above, i.e. as you make the perimeter-minimizing disk containing point p smaller and smaller its boundary becomes more and more similar to a distance circle centered at p. But I would like a (reference to) a proof of this.

Comment: Have you thought of using the exponential map to reduce the question to the constant curvature case?

Comment: I have not, because I am not familiar with the exponential map, but I will look into it, thank you. It sounds useful because geodesic circles/distance circles do have constant geodesic curvature (and are therefore perimeter-extremizing) in surfaces of constant Gaussian curvature.

Comment: The exponential map is the map from the tangent space to the Riemannian manifold which is an isometry in the radial directions, and satisfies Gauss's lemma.  What is relevant here is a variation of the exponential map, which would be the composition of the inverse of the exponential map of the sphere of curvature $K$ (its value at the point $Q$), with the exponential map of the surface.  This would be an almost isometry in small neighborhoods, and may be enough to answer your question.